# Reset function on window resize

Tags: jquery, restart

I'm using the SlimScroll plugin for my website.

I would like to reset/restart the slimscroll function on window resize, because the height and width should be changed according to the height and width of the `#content_wrapper` div.

I tried it trough several ways but nothing seemed to do the trick. Below my current code. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

```
$('#content_wrapper').slimScroll({
    width: $('#content_wrapper').css({'width':(($(window).width())-240)+'px'}),
    height: $('#content_wrapper').css({'height':(($(window).height())-65)+'px'})
});

// scrollbar onresize resetten
$(window).resize(function(){    
    $('#content_wrapper').slimScroll({
        width: $('#content_wrapper').css({'width':(($(window).width())-240)+'px'}),
        height: $('#content_wrapper').css({'height':(($(window).height())-65)+'px'})
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you subtracting 240 and 65 from the window.width?

Comment: Because 65px is the height of the footer, and 240px is the width of the menu.

Comment: I see. Just to make it look better, try putting the new width/height in variables and setting the variables in the slimScroll function. (I also noticed you have parentheses around `$(window)>height()`--you don't need that).

Comment: What i dont understand, why you do this `height: $('#content_wrapper').css({'height':(($(window).height())-65)+'px'})`. Actually the return of the $().. expresison is a jQuery object not a size (also with the width). btw the others seems good.

Answer (score 7):

Just ran into this problem today and this works for me:
when initializing slimScroll, it adds a div with class "slimScrollDiv". You can alter the height of this div and set it the same as your wrapper div...

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#scrollDiv').slimScroll({
      height: 'auto'
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
      var h=$(window).height()-250;
      $('#scrollDiv').height(h);
      $('.slimScrollDiv').height(h);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

For version 0.5.0, replace the following:

```
// set up initial height
getBarHeight();
```

with:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
     getBarHeight();
     showBar();
});
```

I found this on http://dt.infolearn.com.gr/2012/03/jquery-slimscroll-refresh-on-window-resize/ and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question was asked long back but I faced the same issue and found some work around, here is my solution for the problem you faced.

```
// Resetting slim scroll
function applySlimScroll(){
    $('#content_wrapper').slimScroll({
        width: $('#content_wrapper').css({'width':(($(window).width())-240)+'px'}),
        height: $('#content_wrapper').css({'height':(($(window).height())-65)+'px'})
    });
}

// Resetting slim scroll
function resetSlimScrollLessonSlide(){
    $('.slimScrollDiv #content_wrapper').unwrap();
    $('.slimScrollBar, .slimScrollRail').remove();
}

// Let the resize event interval be larger, so resized in 500ms!
function resizedw(){
    resetSlimScrollLessonSlide();
    applySlimScroll()
}

var doit;
$(window).resize(function () {
    clearTimeout(doit);
    doit = setTimeout(resizedw, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
$('#content_wrapper').slimScroll({
    width: (($(window).width())-240)+'px',
    height: (($(window).height())-65)+'px'
});

// scrollbar onresize resetten
$(window).resize(function(){    
    $('#content_wrapper').slimScroll({
        width: (($(window).width())-240)+'px',
        height: (($(window).height())-65)+'px'
    });
});
```